# Why reference with operator = works but with constructor don't?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, variable-initialization

As far as I know the following statements are the same:

```
A a1(1);
A a2=1;
```

Header:

```
class A
{
   public:
      A(int num){}
};
```

But when using reference it won't compile

```
class B{
   private:
      int m_a = 0;
      int& m_b(m_a);

   public:
      B(int num):
      {
      }
};
```

got compile error stating m_a is not a type name
but when doing this with = it works:

```
class B
{
   private:
      int m_a = 0;
      int& m_b = m_a;

   public:
      B(int num):
      {
      }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In-class member initialization is different from other forms of initialization.

The only supported syntax for in-class member initialization are:

```
int& m_b = m_a;
int& m_b{m_a};
```

You can read more about it at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization.